# Is the following $f(x,y)=(−x ^2 ,y^2)$ with the domain $ D = { ( x,y ) ∈ R^2 ∣ x \leq y , y \geq 0 } $

Tags: functions

Is the following $f(x,y)=(−x^2 ,y^2)$ with the domain  $D = \{ ( x,y ) ∈ R^2  ∣   x \leq y , y \geq 0 \} $ bijective?

I have been told it is, but what is wrong with this counterexample?

$(-4, 5) \in R^2$ since $-4 \leq 5$ and $5 > 0$. Hence, $f(-4,5) = (-16,25)$

$(4, 5) \in R^2$ since $4 \leq 5$ and $5 > 0$. Hence, $f(4,5) = (-16,25)$

This by definition is not injective, and thus not bijective. Have I missed something or misunderstanding something with the notation? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: "*I have been told it is not, but what is wrong with this counterexample?*"  Why do you think there is something wrong your counterexample?  Why do you think your counterexample contradicts the statement "*it is not (bijective)*"?

Comment: You have been told it isn't, you've found a counterexample to injectivity, and so have verified what you have been told. There doesn't appear to be any source of doubt here, so I'm not really sure why you're asking about it. Surely this is an open-and-shut case?

Comment: My apologies, I have been told it is bijective, which I think is wrong.

Comment: It is correct to say that the function is not bijective.  Your counterexample explaining why  the function is not bijective is correct.

Comment: A small nitpick... you write "*$(-4,5)\in R^2$ since...*" this should read "$(-4,5)\in D$" instead since being in the domain is what is important here... not being in some tangentially related set.  Similarly, the word "*hence*" is out of place here.

Comment: I'm not sure what the codomain is, so I can't comment on surjectivity, but if it were $x \le y, \color{red}{x} \ge 0$ instead, it would be injective at least.